# Crystal Reports Pie Chart - How to show 0 values in legend

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, report, pie-chart

I am creating pie charts in Crystal Reports to show the number of grades awarded to a student in various tests throughout the year. A student can be awarded a grade 5, 4, 3, 2 or 1 only. Here is an example of a pie chart for one student.[image]

This student did 5 assessment points in the class shown in 2014. He got a grade 5 for one assessment, Grade 4 for 3 assessments and then one Grade 3 for another assessment.

Is there any way, in the legend, of showing the colours that are used for Grades 2 or 1 and showing them as 0%. that is, how can I show all 5 grades in the legend, and, if a student hasn't received that grade, it still shows in the legend with a count of 0 and 0% next to it?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your requirement is something out of box.....sorry for that... because what can a pie show if it is a `Zero` chart is already filled `100%` where is the place to show `Zero` and how can a zero can be shown...one way around that I would suggest is to create a your won legend and show the values for all grades and display `Zero` if the grade is `Zero`

Comment: I decided that the only way to do this was to go back to the SQL behind the report and to create a view which does exactly what I need. Using common table expressions and joins I was able to create all of the grades even if a boy did not receive that particular grade. From that, I then created the pie chart based on this data.